# How do i limit my own element to contain only plain text?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

How do I create a block element, which can only contain plain text? (No bold, italic and so on).

I have registered my element as:

```
model.schema.register(mtHeaderLine, {
   // Changing inheritAllFrom to '$block' creates an editable element
   // but then it can contain bold text.
   inheritAllFrom: '$text',  
   allowIn: mtHeaderDiv,
   isBlock: true
});
```

And then I downcast with:

```
editor.conversion.for('downcast').add(downcastElementToElement( { model: mtHeaderLine, view: 'div' }
```

But that creates an element which I can't edit.

I also tried to downcast with:

```
view: (modelElement, viewWriter ) => { 
    const viewElement=viewWriter.createEditableElement('div',{ 'class': (mtHeaderLine) ,isghost: isGhost });
    return viewElement;
}
```

But that did not give me an editable element either.

Comment: Hi, why not to work with a configuration file to remove features ? https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/configuration.html#removing-features

Comment: Because I only want to remove the feature, for my own specific element. I still want bold and italic to work on all the other text

Comment: Yes, you can create a config file that you only apply depending on your needs (typically for your only desired plain text block). I may not have understood what you exactly want btw...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`Schema#addAttributeCheck()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_schema-Schema.html#function-addAttributeCheck). That method allows you to register a callback which will disallow all attributes on `$text` which is in some context (e.g. a child of a model `<plaintext>` element):

```
function MyPlugin( editor ) {
    editor.model.schema.register( 'plaintext', {
        inheritAllFrom: '$block'
    } );

    editor.model.schema.addAttributeCheck( ( ctx, attrName ) => {
        if ( ctx.endsWith( 'plaintext $text' ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    } );

    editor.conversion.elementToElement( {
        model: 'plaintext',
        view: 'div'
    } );
}

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.getElementById( 'editor' ), {
        plugins: [ ...ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins, MyPlugin ]
    } )
    .then( editor => {
        window.editor = editor;
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/rvas7pLn/1/

Comment: That works perfectly. Only small issue, is that the bold button still looks like you can press it. But that might just be my custom gui code since I don't use the standard toolbar.

Comment: In the above solution the command should be disabled. So if your button triggers the command (like it should), nothing should happen anyway. State binding is something that you'd need to implement together with yout UI too.

Comment: @Rainmar What should I do, if I also want my buttons show the fact that they are disabled? My buttons currently listen to changes with on("change",(evt,name,isEnabled) which works fine if a command is explicit disabled. But no change event is ever fired by the addAttributeCheck function. Should I listen to something else?